# In angular test I type the command ng test, but nothing happens

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am using angular 15.2.5 and am trying to run karma unittests. When I type ng test,
the output is:
One or more browsers which are configured in the project's Browserslist configuration will be ignored as ES5 output is not supported by the Angular CLI.
Ignored browsers: kaios 2.5, op_mini all
⠋ Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...%
Then nothing happens. What can I do? Unfortunately I am not allowed, to show the code.
Regards, Horst

I tried adapting the versions and need the unittests running

Answer (score 0):

Hello I fixed it updating the versions of the libraries of the package.json to the current ones. Now the tests run.